# ejabberd Hook vs IQ Handler

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd and need some guidance.  I have not been able to locate detail documents on ejabberd so this forum is my only hope.  I know erlang good enough to write my own module and also was able to modify mod_roster to meet my requirements.  This is the issue I need help with.  I would like the users to send an IQ request to the server and the server should be able to process the request and send back a response.  I have tried using hooks but I am not sure which to use.  My IQ Handlers are not firing at all.

Any example provided would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Will

Comment: Have you tried https://www.ejabberd.im/forum ?

Comment: Oh yes but responses seem very limited if at all.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add an `ejabberd_local` iq handler.

A good example is for example on `mod_last`: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_last.erl#L65

You can check the code flow for `process_local_iq`.

Comment: I did all of this already. I created a new namespace "ag-software:weather" and added IQ handlers for both  ejabberd_local and ejabberd_sm.  When the client sent the request none of the handlers are firing.   The client send <iq id="MX_4" type="get" to="sarah@adminpc/adminPC" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <weather xmlns="ag-software:weather">
    <zip>9098</zip>
  </weather>
</iq>

Comment: The server would respond with <iq from="sarah@adminpc/adminPC" to="karen@adminpc/MatriX" type="error" id="MX_4" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <weather xmlns="ag-software:weather">
    <zip>9098</zip>
  </weather>
  <error code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
  </error>
</iq>

Comment: Add debug printout in your code and share exact code and logs.

Comment: Found the issue. Its rather silly actually.  I was sending the request to another user and not the server.  Once I changed the recipient to the host name only it worked.